# How to cross over the corresponding elements of matrices (genetic algorithm)

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm working on some genetic algorithm code, and I'm seeking help to select the corresponding elements of a matrix in order to perform crossover on the chromosomes in population of individuals

I want to apply a function of crossover between `a11*a11, a12*a12, ...` and so on, but I'm failing to select the corresponding matrix elements.

Here's my code:

```
string1 = Table[Random[Integer], {stringLength, 2, 7}];
string2 = Table[Random[Integer], {stringLength, 2, 7}];
Print[string1, string2] 

docrossover[{string1_, string2_}] := Module[{stle, cut, temp1, temp2}, 
    stle = Length[string1]; 
    cut = Random[Integer, {1, stle - 2}]; 
    temp1 = Join[Take[string1, cut], Drop[string2, cut]]; 
    temp2 = Join[Take[string2, cut], Drop[string1, cut]]; 
    Return[{cut, temp1, temp2}]
  ]; 

docrossover[{string1, string2}]
```

Comment: This is a very unclear question. Crossover, e.g., has differing definitions. Please provide precise definitions/examples of what you're trying to accomplish, with germane code relating to your effort so far.

Comment: here is the example of cross over i'd made in  yet.. 2ndly i mentioned the word GA (genetic algo) to clarify the cross over in two indivudals...string1 = Table[Random[Integer], {stringLength, 2, 7}];
string2 = Table[Random[Integer], {stringLength, 2, 7}];
Print[string1, string2]
docrossover[{string1_, string2_}] :=
  Module[{stle, cut, temp1, temp2},
   stle = Length[string1];
   cut = Random[Integer, {1, stle - 2}];
   temp1 = Join[Take[string1, cut], Drop[string2, cut]];
   temp2 = Join[Take[string2, cut], Drop[string1, cut]];
   Return[{cut, temp1, temp2}]];
docrossover[{string1, string2}]

Comment: Please add the code as a code block in your question (use the edit link right under the question to edit it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I'll leave my answer here just in case, but I think m_goldberg's interpretation of the OP's request in his answer makes more sense than mine.

---

Let's generate two random matrices:

```
SeedRandom[1]

matrixA = RandomInteger[10, {6, 4}]
matrixB = RandomInteger[10, {6, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You seem to want to calculate the crossover by applying some function f to the element-by-element product of the two matrices:

```
crossover = Map[f, matrixA matrixB, {-1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you should be able to define an appropriate function `f` to calculate your crossover value.

Comment: Evidently, your interpretation, and not mine, was the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this will help you.

```
crossover[c1_List, c2_List] /; Length @ c1 == Length @ c2 := 
  Module[{cut, c1a, c1p, c2a, c2p}, 
    cut = RandomInteger[{2, Length @ c1 - 1}]; 
    {c1a, c1p} = {c1[[1 ;; cut]], c1[[cut + 1 ;; -1]]}; 
    {c2a, c2p} = {c2[[1 ;; cut]], c2[[cut + 1 ;; -1]]}; 
    {cut, Join[c1a, c2p], Join[c2a, c1p]}]; 

SeedRandom[42];
genome1 = RandomInteger[1, {6, 8}]
genome2 = RandomInteger[1, {6, 8}]
MapThread[crossover, {genome1, genome2}]
```

[image: GA.png]

Some points of explanation.

1. My notation can be read c -> chromosome, a -> anterior, p -> posterior
2. I make use of *Mathematica*'s ability to make assignments, element by element, between a list of variables and a list of values.
3. I make use of [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html) to break the chromosomes at the chosen point.
4. [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) is a good way to map a function of two variables element-wise over two lists of values.
5. The line `cut = RandomInteger[{2, Length @ c1 - 1}]` was changed from your formulation because *Mathematica*'s lists use 1-based indexing.
6. Calling `Return` at the end of a `Module` is not necessary because the last expression evaluated in the body is automatically returned.

Comment: sir,i need correction in mutation code too...if u help me i'l be gratefull............... {string = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
mutataionrate = .01;
domutation[string_] :=
 Module[{tempstring, i},
  tempstring = string;
  Do[If[Random[] < mutationrate,
    tempstring[[i]] = 1 - tempstring[[i]]],
   {i, StringLength}];
  Return[{tempstring}]]}

Answer (score 1):

I post this for illustration/motivation.

A crossover function based on that suggested by OP code. Note have made no effrot to deal with unequal list lengths and order of arguments.

```
xo[s1_, s2_] := With[{n = RandomInteger[{1, Length[s1] - 2}]},
  n -> {s1[[1 ;; n]]~Join~s2[[n + 1 ;; -1]], 
    s2[[1 ;; n]]~Join~s1[[n + 1 ;; -1]]}]
```

Visualizing cross over of pairs of lists ("chromosomes"):

```
ap[a_, b_] := 
 Column[Map[
   ArrayPlot[{#}, Mesh -> All, 
     ColorFunction -> (Function[x, 
        ColorData["Rainbow"][(x - 1)/(2 Length@#)]]), 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False] &, {a, b}]]
vis[a_, b_] := 
 With[{res = xo[a, b]}, 
  Row[{ap[a, b], "\[RightArrow]", ap @@ (res[[2]]), "  ", res[[1]]}]]
Column[Table[vis[Range[10], Range[10] + 10], {10}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Application to lists for recombination is different matter.